# Laravel count childs of a relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've three models in Laravel.

- `User`
- `Profile`
- `Rating`

A `User` has many `Profiles` and a `Profile` has many `Ratings`.

My goal is to get the total count of ratings owned by a user. Something like this:

```
$user->profiles()->ratings()->count();
```

How can I get this the total count?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User::with('profiles.ratings')->count();
```

should do the trick

You should have a look at [Nested Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: That's exactly what I looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to add function in user model:

```
public function profile()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Profile', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

and add function in profile model:

```
public function rating()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Rating', 'profile_id', 'id');
}
```

and call like:

```
User::withcount('profile.rating');
```